# Bricked Atmega32u4 on hi3518 board

Tags: arduino, embedded-linux

I have an old board

```
# dmesg
Linux version 3.0.8 (pub@BVT-SDK-SERVER3) (gcc version 4.4.1 
(Hisilicon_v100(gcc4.4-290+uclibc_0.9.32.1+eabi+linuxpthread)) ) #1 Tue Mar 
11 17:36:34 HKT 2014
CPU: ARM926EJ-S [41069265] revision 5 (ARMv5TEJ), cr=00053177
CPU: VIVT data cache, VIVT instruction cache
Machine: hi3518
```

With a Arduino Leonardo embedded on it which is bricked (I have put a bad sketch on it) and now I can't upload something:

```
Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Is there a way to access to this Arduino using the Linux system?

I can access to the board by wifi or serial debug port.
I can access to the Arduino by serial port.

Comment: You can reflash the bootloader (it'll also remove the sketch) by another Arduino as ISP

Comment: And can I do that directly from the Linux on the board ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you for the clue. I never flashed a new bootloader before.

I used a script from [reset leonardo comport](https://github.com/p1ne/arduino-leonardo-uploader)
And a firmware from [leonardo flash](https://github.com/adafruit/Caterina-Bootloader/blob/master/Built%20Firmwares/Caterina-Leonardo.hex)
(I need to unplug-replug the usb to achieve a good flashing)